# Space between 12'x24' tile is it 1/8 or 1/16

Tags: tile, leveling

I bought a T-lock leveling system.
I'm stacking my tile vertically.
What space should I leave between the tiles and also between the tile and wall.
Shall I use 1/16" spacers or 1/8" spacers?

Comment: I'm going to guess that those are 12"x24" tiles, because at 12x24 _feet_ that's kinda _huge_! :)

Answer (score 1):

This will be a matter of opinion but my opinion would be to have at least 1/8" spacing between tiles. You want enough space for the grout to grab onto. If you're using a contrasting grout for a designer affect, then a larger spacing could be used.

Comment: As Jack stated, it is a matter of opinion. Just had tile done in my kitchen and family room.  I did not the distinctive borders around the tile and went with 1/16" gap and a matching grout color.  The floor almost appears to be seamless.  With 1/8" or wider, the tile will have the checker board look.  Go to the tile store and layout your pattern in the different gaps and see which pattern looks the best to you.

Comment: @JACK So opinions are okay if you do it and SE should not close the question?

Comment: @LeeSam  Don't know where this is coming from but I guess it's up to the moderators and voters. It's helping with a home improvement project so I guess it passed.

Comment: @JACK You voted to close “moisture barrier or vapor barrier” question that is current.

Comment: @LeeSam The OP didn't even know if they had a moisture barrier and admitted to many comment and questions. The site asks for one question.  What do the other who voted to close think?